# Kafka Stream Stops Reconnecting when the node is down for a long time

Tags: apache-kafka

We are facing an issue where when the kafka stream is not able to reconnect after the Node goes down for longer period and we are getting  this error as mentione below.

```
Error connecting to node localhost:9093 (id: -7 rack: null), 2021-10-21 00:21:14.567 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-135] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect - [Producer clientId=producer-135] Error connecting to node localhost:9093 (id: -7 rack: null)
```

Though we haven't used the "reconnect.backoff.ms" but it should have a default value setup for this property. Is it needed to provide this property and not to use the default setup to auto reconnect.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow , Please make sure to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and hot to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) properly .

Answer (score 0):

The backoff time is time **between** retires. If you exhaust the connection retries, it stops connecting